# PHP: An efficient way to insert a list to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

Merely due to the sake of being efficient I would like to hear some advises from the PHP expers here. (Actually this question goes out all developers that mess with database connections on a regular basis)

Assume you have one **personId** and this id has multiple **numbers**. You have a table with columns **pID**,**nums**

From the php side you retrieve these numbers in an array. Now my question comes to place. Do you do something like;

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
   //Call the insert query over and over again
}
```

Or there is obviously a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you want to do a bulk insert - it's faster to execute one composite statement, than lots of individual inserts, so try:

```
$data is your array
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $data as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['field1']).'")';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: I assumed the tag implied it's MySQL :)

Answer (score 1):

If your data set is really large, you can look at dumping your values into a file, and then executing "LOAD DATA INFILE" (will only work if MySQL runs on the same host as your script).

Alternatively, you can use one insert query:

```
INSERT INTO table(pid,nums) VALUES (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), ... -- etc
```

with multiple values.